# How to make ObjectListView work in obfuscated code?

Tags: c#, obfuscation, objectlistview

[ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/download.html) stops working when i obfuscate the code. The issue seems to be centred around using AspectName to set the column in MainForm.designer.cs
E.g:

```
this.olvColumn1.AspectName = "Name";
```

The Obfuscator could be renaming all my methods. Any advice on how to fix this issue?

Comment: What is the obfuscator you use?

Comment: @IVAAAN123 Eazfuscator.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AspectName` is obviously using the name of the property, which is defeated by obfuscating.

You'll have to install an `AspectGetter` delegate instead:

```
this.olvColumn1.AspectGetter = delegate(object x) {
    return ((YourModelClass)x).Name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Could you please explain more about "YourModelClass" in your code.  Currently "this.olvColumn1.AspectGetter" is in  MainForm.designer.cs which i cannot edit, so i guess i need to move the code out in to Form1.cs. I had added the column names to ObjectListView using "Edit columns..." option on the control available in designer view in Visual Studio. A more detailed sample code would be very helpful.

Comment: The `AspectGetter` should not show up in the designer file.  If it does anyway, you could move it to Form1.cs. Normally you would just attach the delegate in your `Form1.cs` like Grammarian pointed out. `AspectGetter` takes precedence over `AspectName`. Within the `AspectGetter`, you can return any value from any source. The OLV will use ToString to display the value. Note that you have to also attach the `AspectPutter` if you want to edit values within the OLV. `YourModelClass` was just an example. `x` contains the underlying model of the respective row. Cas it to whatever your model type is.